# "Sign Up" not working for mobile devices for Ruby on Rails 6 app with Devise gem

Tags: devise, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 app that allows users to create an account. Unfortunately when users are viewing my site on a mobile device, they are not able to create an account when they click the "Sign Up" button.

They get a "The webpage is not available" message[image]

I have no idea how to debug this.
I am hosting this through Digital Ocean.

The weird part is that I am use Heroku for staging purposes, and when users go the the Heroku version of the app, the "Sign Up" button works perfectly on mobile.

The code is exactly the same on Heroku and Digital Ocean, so I don't know why Digital Ocean gets this screen.

I'm a junior Rails Dev, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We solved this issues by removing the "autofocus: true" on the signup form! Try it and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: This fixed it for me too. The signup form was breaking when linking to it, but worked after refreshing the page. Only a problem on iOS safari.

Answer (score 1):

So I discovered that once I fixed all my Javascript errors, this issue disappeared, and people could log in and also create accounts on mobile devices.

I guess mobile devices are sensitive to javascript errors in a way that desktop browsers aren't.